# .htaccess для SEO оптимизации

Tags: seo

Мне нужен шаблон файла .htaccess для правильной работы SEO, он должен отдавать 200 код ответа для главного зеркала (https://site.ru) и 301 код по не основным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я уже 2 года работаю в SEO и путём проб и ошибок подобрал универсальный и лёгкий файл .htaccess для SEO, вот такой:

```
RewriteEngine On
# www переадресовывать на без www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.proflist-ryzan\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://proflist-ryzan.ru//$1 [R=301,L]

# если по порту 80 (http), то переадресуем на ssl
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://proflist-ryzan.ru/$1 [R=301,L]  

# если по порту 443 (https), то переадресуем на http
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:80/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Этот файл определяет основное зеркало сайта как https://...? без ошибок сервера при проверке в яндекс вебмастере (https://webmaster.yandex.ru/tools/server-response/)

Answer (score 0):

Сама постановка вопроса "настроить .htaccess для SEO" не корректная. Кроме того, эти настройки не решат все ваши проблемы по редиректам. Для оптимизации сайта - ему необходим полноценный технический аудит. Настройки одногно лишь .htaccess не достаточно.

Кроме того, в зависимости от движка и самого сервера эти настройки могут отличаться. Например, на одном сервере одно и то же правило переадресации может работать, а может не работать, потому что сами серверы могут быть по-разному настроены.

Привожу пример одной из настроек .htaccess. Но некоторые из них для вас могут не работать, поэтому некоторые представлены в двух вариантах.

```
#Обозначаем кодировку сайта
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

# Директива включает редиректы.
RewriteEngine on
# Без директивы (.*) = /$1 будет /var/wwww/site/web/$1  с директивой  = /$1
RewriteBase /

# Разрешает переход по символическим ссылкам.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# запретить отображение ошибок  (требование монитора качества)
php_flag display_errors off

# 301 с IP на домен
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.222\.333\.444
RewriteRule (.*) https://site.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# 301 с IP на домен способ 2
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[\d.]+$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.com/$1 [L,R=permanent]

#301 c index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]

# 301 http → https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# 301 www → без www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

# Проверяем, повторяется ли слеш (//) более двух раз.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
# Исключаем все лишние слеши.
RewriteRule .* /$0 [R=301,L]

# Добавляем слеш(/), если его нет, и это не файл
# Если слеша в конце нет.
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
# Не является файлом.
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# В URL нет точки (файл).
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
# В URL есть хоть один символы
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)$
# Добавляем слеш в конце.
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```